# How do I patch this hole in my vinyl window frame?

Tags: repair, windows, vinyl

Not sure what the previous homeowner was thinking when he drilled this hole, but what would be the best material to patch it with?

As you can see in the picture, it's a purely aesthetic fix but I'm remodeling the room and I'm obsessed with details like this.

[image: photo of hole]

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything that won't look like a patch. You could back the hole and fill it with a putty, but it will always look like a hole... Or you could paint it and it will always look like a silly painted vinyl window. 

I know this isn't what you were after, but I'd find a way to live with the hole.

Comment: Looks like it might have been used for security. Either an alarm sensor, or more likely you could put something through the hole to block the sliding window. It could then be left open for fresh air, but not open enough for an intruder to fit through.

Comment: Yes, it looks just the size of the alarm sensor hole in the link that user156+ posted below.

Comment: It's a second story window, but it's was a nursery/small child's room. So maybe it was some sort of security pin to prevent the window from being opened too wide so the kid couldn't push out through the screen? But is the best solution really one that does irreversible damage? Thanks for helping me solve the mystery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try vinyl plugs that can be found in hardware/home improvement stores. The plugs come in various diameters. If there isn't one for the hole's size, you may have to drill it larger to the size of the plug so that it will fit.

Also found this [kit](http://www.vinyldoc.com/products/hole/), may be this will be an alternative option.

Answer (score 2):

Does it line up with a hole or notch in the top of the window when it is closed?  Then it was for a security pin or other lock.

The easiest thing would be to glue a larger piece of thin vinyl over it.  Anything else is going to be more noticeable unless you are a master craftsman.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not so big hole so you can use POP for filling it & after that you can paint it & hang a wall hanging on it so that it looks beautiful & hole didn't appear anymore.

Comment: What is _POP_ ?